# Question regarding optimising reading and writing to a file through mmap(2)?

Tags: c, macos, mmap

I am having some issues with optimisations in my code. I would try my best to explain the scenario I am in. If not clear please ask.

The problem is straight. Previously I had 2 separate files that I was opening in the same process and calling `mmap(2)` on both separately. The first mapping is more frequently accessed compared to second mapping.(both for reading and writing)
I thought to optimise the code more, instead of using 2 separate files I could simply place the contents of first file(whose size really small compared to second file) in the beginning of the second file and shift root of the second file ahead by the required offset.
This would avoid usage of 2 files, hence avoiding calls to `open(2)` and `mmap(2)`. As this setup code (that calls `open(2)` and `mmap(2)`) will get called at least 100,000+ times, removing these 2 calls should have mattered. But I don’t know why the accesses to the portion that I shifted to the beginning of the 2nd file became much slower. On google I read somewhere that it maybe the case of some page caching but I am not sure if it is the case because writing operation got almost 10-20 times slower. Please suggest me how can I improve this?

UPDATE:

As per the tests I conducted in past, it didn't make much difference using two files or one file. I presume this question would require some deep study on how mmap deals with pages.

Comment: I guess that writing to either is invalidating the caching of the other. I don't know a solution other than to keep them separate - but maybe someone else does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two pointers from the same mapping:

```
int len = 1300,
    off = 600,
    prot = PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
    flags = MAP_SHARED,
    fd = open("file", O_RDWR);
char *map = mmap(NULL, len, prot, flags, fd, 0),
     *map2 = map + off;

*map = 'a';
*map2 = 'b';
```

Don't use the `offset` argument unless it's a multiple of the page size (usually 4096).

Answer (score -1):

In order to get the same sorts of I/O patterns with a single file as you got with two files, make sure that the 2nd part of the file starts at a page boundary (4K). You may have to pad the 1st part out to make that happen.